# inline list broken by hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a pretty simple `<ul>` consisting of images that will display the persons name and a brief bit of info when hovered over. My intention for the `<ul>` is for it to be horizontal, which it was prior to adding the hover aspect(`<figcaption>`).

My questions:
1. Why is the `<ul>` no longer horizontal, and how do I rectify this?
2. How can I have the hover information display in the same spot centered beneath the `<ul>` regardless of which `<li>` is selected?

I've used [this article from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/a-really-nice-way-to-handle-popup-information/) for help, but it doesn't address my specific concerns.

(I'd prefer to keep this strictly HTML/CSS if at all possible.)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7McEX/)

```
ul.stylists {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 582px;
}

ul.stylists li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

ul.stylists li:last-child {
    padding-right: none;
}

figcaption {
   display: none;
   opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

ul.stylists li:hover figcaption {
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try this!just put the `position:absolute` in `ul.stylists li:hover figcaption` and `display:inline-block` in `ul.stylists li` see here...

http://jsfiddle.net/bgajjar1/7McEX/13/

Answer (score 2):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7McEX/7/
make the li into a `position: relative`
and then make the figcaption into `position: absolute`

Comment: Looks good to me, although the OP didn't specify what the end result should be.

Comment: The fiddle seems to work exactly as I'd wish, however if you take a look at the live site[http://nevaehstudiodallas.com/about/].. the list is still vertically oriented. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Here the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7McEX/11/)

change in `figcaption` the `display: none:` to `display: block;`

and remove in `ul.stylists li:hover figcaption` the `display: block;`

CSS:

```
figcaption {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;  
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

ul.stylists li:hover figcaption {
   opacity: 1;
}
```